# Using jquery .each to loop through divs and retrieve data-src

Tags: jquery, each

I have a div with a bunch of children divs, each with a `data-src` attribute. I'm trying to loop over these and return them in the console using the `.each` jquery function. I'm using the code below:

```
function rolloverImages() {
  $('.thumbnail-wrapper').mouseover(function() {
    var rollovers = $(this).find('rolloverimages');
    rollovers.each(function() {
      console.log( index + ": " + $(this).data('src') );
    });
  });
}

<div class="rolloverimages">
                                        <div data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-ochre-5.jpg"></div>
                                        <div data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-ochre-8.jpg"></div>
                                        <div data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-ochre-9.jpg"></div>
                                        <div data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-ochre-3.jpg"></div>
                                        <div data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-ochre-6.png"></div>
                                        <div data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-ochre-4.jpg"></div>
                                        <div data-src=""></div>
                                        <div data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-ochre-7.jpg"></div>
                                    </div>
```

However, what I have isn't working. I believe it might be something to do with the this i'm using the console log.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using it incorrectly use like this:

```
$('.rolloverimages div').each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).attr('data-src')); // this will output the value for data-src in console
})
```

you can then do whatever inside the loop.

Note this is not a copy-paste solution - amend for your need, but this is how the function works.

ref:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Thanks mate, I just realised I was missing the dot on the class and I wasn't targeting the individual divs. all working now :)